# Amazon MWS feed api not giving the result instantly . Is there any work arround?

Tags: amazon-mws

We are working on amazon MWS feed api for doing the lot of stuffs like.

- Publishing product
- Updating inventory
- Updating tracking info for orders.

But we are facing two problem basically.

- 1st Amazon gets throttled if we cross their limit of request which is basically mostly with in 15 per hour.
- 2nd Amazon is taking the feed after we don't have any info what actually happened whether that all the entries in the feed go through or some failed ?

Anyone has found any work around to these problems. I know we can create a system on our side and keep track of each feed and the data we are sending and from feed Submission result we can do the required changes in our database till that we will keep the status as hold / feed processing. But I want to know is there any simple work around this.

Thank in Advance
Sandeep

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing 15 requests per hour or less, you should not hit any throttling. The quota is [30 SubmitFeed() calls per hour](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_Throttling.html).

The entire SubmitFeed process is described in the [MWS Developer Docs](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_Overview.html). In short, it works like this:

1. SubmitFeed() will return a FeedSubmissionID
2. Keep calling GetFeedSubmissionList() with above ID to check its processing state, wait >=2 minutes inbetween calls. Feeds are usually processed within 10 minutes, but sometimes may take as long as an hour to process.
3. Once above call returns `_DONE_` you calL GetFeedSubmissionResult() which returns a list of things that failed

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What you are saying that I understand perfectly. But GetFeedSubmissionResult result sending reference as MessageId. So for that we have keep track on our system what we send on which message means basically building a system on our side. Is there anything else possible except feed in amazon like ebay i.e. no throttling and instant response on data we send.

Comment: @SandeepKumarMohanty There is no alternative to `SubmitFeed` which would process data instantly. Make sure you understand the difference between `FeedSubmissionId` and `MessageId`. The former is assigned by Amazon, the latter is part of the feed and is set by your code.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the process - didn't see this in the (pretty poor) documentation.

Comment: After getting Feed submission id , I keep calling get feed submission status, and it show its submitted success, but Its not reflecting on the sellercentral, whats the reason? Thanks again.