# Amazon API Order Fulfillment Feed not updating order data

Tags: c#, amazon-mws

I am trying to update shipment details(carrier,shipment tracking number etc) of orders by submitting order fulfillment feed.Feed is submitting successfully.But order data is not updating.I have downloaded sample c# code from amazon to submit feed

```
            String accessKeyId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            String secretAccessKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

            MarketplaceWebServiceConfig config = new MarketplaceWebServiceConfig();
            config.ServiceURL = "https://mws.amazonservices.com";

            const string applicationName = "CSharpSampleCode";
            const string applicationVersion = "1.0";

            MarketplaceWebService.MarketplaceWebService service =
                new MarketplaceWebServiceClient(
                    accessKeyId,
                    secretAccessKey,
                    applicationName,
                    applicationVersion,
                    config);


            const string merchantId = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
            const string marketplaceId = "ATVPDKIKX0DER";
            SubmitFeedRequest request = new SubmitFeedRequest();
            request.Merchant = merchantId;
            request.MarketplaceIdList = new IdList();
            request.MarketplaceIdList.Id = new List<string>(new string[] { marketplaceId });

            
            request.FeedContent = File.Open(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/amazonorderfeed/f2.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            
            request.ContentMD5 = MarketplaceWebServiceClient.CalculateContentMD5(request.FeedContent);
            request.FeedContent.Position = 0;

            request.FeedType = "_POST_FULFILLMENT_ORDER_REQUEST_DATA_";

            SubmitFeedResponse response = service.SubmitFeed(request);
```

my xml content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>CSharpSampleCode</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
<Message>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<OrderFulfillment>
<AmazonOrderID>111-1111111-1111111</AmazonOrderID>
<FulfillmentDate>2015-02-21T15:36:33-08:00</FulfillmentDate>
<FulfillmentData>
<CarrierCode>UPS</CarrierCode>
<ShippingMethod>Second Day</ShippingMethod>
<ShipperTrackingNumber>1234567890</ShipperTrackingNumber>
</FulfillmentData>
<Item>
<AmazonOrderItemCode>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</AmazonOrderItemCode>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Item>
</OrderFulfillment>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

After submitting feed I am getting FeedSubmissionId,RequestId,FeedProcessingStatus:submitted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After submitting a feed, you need to wait for it to process and check its result.

[how to check the processing state and results of MWS feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402337/amazon-mws-feed-api-not-giving-the-result-instantly-is-there-any-work-arround/26429210#26429210)

Edit: I found a flaw in your XML: `CSharpSampleCode` is not a valid `MerchantIdentifier`

Comment: Thanks.My MerchantIdentifier was wrong.Though I already tried "GetFeedSubmissionResult" method before but I was just checking GetFeedSubmissionResultResponse object. I did not check "feedSubmissionResult.xml" file generated in between my "InvokeGetFeedSubmissionResult" function execution. And I removed Item tag also which is not needed in my case..It worked... :)

Comment: Thanks for that Link, pretty sure this helps me debugging my feed.

Answer (score 0):

If the order fulfillment feed isn't working for you, you could also try using the [confirmShipment](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/orders-api-v0-reference#confirmshipment) API call in the [SP-API Orders API](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/orders-api-v0-reference).  See my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77630357/1003451) for more explanation.